# JNA call with String behaves differently from one with byte[]

Tags: java, jna, mpv

I have a JNA Java interface for a C function `mpv_set_option_string` defined as:

```
public interface MPV extends StdCallLibrary {
    MPV INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("lib/mpv-1.dll", MPV.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    long mpv_create();
    int mpv_initialize(long handle);
    int mpv_set_option_string(long handle, String name, String data);
}
```

When I call this like this:

```
System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "UTF8");

long handle = MPV.INSTANCE.mpv_create();
int error = MPV.INSTANCE.mpv_initialize(handle);
error = MPV.INSTANCE.mpv_set_option_string(handle, "keep-open", "always");
```

I get an error back (`-5`) from the last call, indicating the option (`keep-open`) is not found.

However, if I change the JNA function signature to:

```
int mpv_set_option_string(long handle, byte[] name, byte[] data);
```

...and then call it like this:

```
error = MPV.INSTANCE.mpv_set_option_string(
    handle, 
    "keep-open\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
    "always\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
);
```

...it returns no error (`0`) and works correctly (or so it seems).

What I don't get is, JNA is supposed to encode `String` by default as `char *` with UTF-8 encoding and `NUL` terminated (exactly what I do manually), yet I get different results.

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing W32OPTIONS to a library that isn't a WIN32 API.

By default, JNA maps `String` to `char*`, so removing the options should fix the issue for you.

You should also be using an explicit native type for your handle instead of Java `long`.  `Pointer` is probably correct in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the issue, although I'm not 100% sure what is happening.

It seems that using `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` means it will use the UNICODE settings (because `w32.ascii` property is `false`).   This looked okay to me, as `mpv-1.dll` works with UTF-8 strings only, which is Unicode.

However, now I'm *guessing* that in this case it means it will call a wide-char version of the library function (and if that doesn't exist, still call the original function), and probably means it encodes Strings with two bytes per character.  This is because most Win32 libraries have an ASCII and WIDE version of methods accepting strings, but nothing for UTF-8.

Since `mpv-1.dll` only accepts UTF-8 (and isn't really Win32), strings should be just encoded as bytes in UTF-8 format (basically, just leave them alone).  To let JNA know this, either donot pass a `W32APIOptions` map at all, or select the `ASCII_OPTIONS` manually.